# Regex: Match any word that is not the one defined by regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract the words between the two bracket "blocks" and also the word in first brackets (RUNNING or STOPPED).

Example (extract the bolded part):

```
[ **RUNNING** ]  **My First Application**  [Pid: 4194]

[ **RUNNING** ]  **Second app (some data)**  [Pid: 5248]

[ **STOPPED** ]  **Logger App**
```

So, as you can see, the [Pid: X] part is optional. I can write the regex as follows:

```
\[\s+(RUNNING|STOPPED)\s+\]\s+([^\[]+).*
```

and it will work. But this would fail if App name would contain the '[' character. I tried the following, but it won't work:

```
\[\s+(RUNNING|STOPPED)\s+\]\s+(?!\[Pid)+.*
```

My idea was to match any words/characters that are not starting with "[Pid", but I guess this would match any words that are not followed by "[Pid".

Is there any way to do exactly that: Match any word that is not "[Pid", i.e. match the part until first appearing of "[Pid" substring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\[\s+(RUNNING|STOPPED)\s+\]\s+([^\[]*(?:\[(?!Pid:)[^\[]*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lR2Qmi/2)

**Details**:

- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(RUNNING|STOPPED)` - Group 1 capturing either `RUNNING` or `STOPPED`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\]` - a literal `]`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `([^\[]*(?:\[(?!Pid:)[^\[]*)*)` - Group 2 capturing:

  - `[^\[]*` - zero or more chars other than `[`
  - `(?:\[(?!Pid:)[^\[]*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `\[(?!Pid:)` - a `[` not followed with `Pid:`
    - `[^\[]*` - zero or more chars other than `[`.

[Java code](http://ideone.com/cGevOJ):

```
String rx = "\\[\\s+(RUNNING|STOPPED)\\s+\\]\\s+([^\\[]*(?:\\[(?!Pid:)[^\\[]*)*)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = p.matcher("[ RUNNING ] My First Application");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: Nice "trick" with "\[(?!Pid:)", but it is too long for my case. I used accepted answer. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: If you want efficiency then you have to put up with longer patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify end of regex as `[Pid` or `end of line` by using this syntax:

```
\[\s+(RUNNING|STOPPED)\s+\]\s+(.*)(\[Pid|$)
```

[Example.](https://regex101.com/r/j6gQKt/2)

Comment: I knew there should be some kind of "trick". Thanks! Although, since I want that inner text, this should be correct answer:
\[\s+(RUNNING|STOPPED)\s+\]\s+(.+)(\[Pid.*|$)

Comment: @Bade just added to code example. But you are missing backslash before last `[`. Also, there is no need to add `.*` after PID if you don't want that value.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks, I'll mark it as answer since it's most concise.

Comment: If your strings are short and only contain 1 match, it is OK, but if they span across multiple lines or you have multiple values of this type on one line, this won't work.

Comment: I agree. This actually won't work. I gave three examples, not the whole string consisting of three lines. So, the third line is matched only if it's at the end of file (thus matching the $ character).

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve it with:

```
\[\ (RUNNING|STOPPED)\ \] # RUNNING or STOPPED -> group 1
(.+?)                     # everything afterwards in the same line lazily
(?:\[Pid:\ (\d+)\]|$)     # [Pid:, numbers -> group 2, optional
```

See it [**working on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/52A9Uc/2).

Comment: I think this doesn't work (example doesn't match either). Shouldn't ".+?" match only the first character since it's non-greedy? Also, in last line you are stating with negative lookahead that there won't be "[Pid" afterwards. At least that's my understanding.

Comment: @Bade: There's no lookahead in the expression. If you're interested, read the detailed explanation on regex101.

Comment: If I put ".+?" in parentheses, my 2nd matching group is "My First Application [Pid: 4194]" - with "[Pid" part included. I don't want it included.

Comment: My bad also, read "?:" as "?!". Now is very similar to accepted answer. Thanks anyway :)